# Android: resolving language resources (in app and in Play Store)

Tags: android, localization, locale, translation

I'm a bit confused by the guidance [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html).

Prior to Android 7, it seems that the device tries the specific locale e.g. `fr_FR` and if there is no such language resource then it strips the country and looks in `fr`.

On this basis, given that I don't have a vast army of translators to translate into each and every local variant, I've been sticking translations into the parent folders, e.g. `fr`, `de` etc.  If the user doesn't like the variant being delivered, there is an option in the app to choose any other.

For Android 7 and above, the guidance seems to be to:

> store resources in the most common parent dialect. For example, if you were storing Spanish resources in the `values-es-rUS` directory before, move them into the `values-b+es+419` directory, which contains Latin American Spanish.

But surely if your Spanish translations are actually for `es_US`, then it doesn't make any sense to treat them as `es_419` (because `es_US` and `es_419` are different)?  Why not just leave them under `es_US`, because it seems that for Android 7 they would be found anyway (by traversing up and then down the tree) even if the device was set to `es_ES` and `es_US` was the only thing available?

For a small developer, with just one translation available for a particular language (e.g. only `es_ES`) is it still a reasonable strategy to stick it into the parent locale folder (e.g. `es`)?  That way, it should be delivered for any requested variant of Spanish, both pre and post Android 7?  But this goes against the above guidance.

And as for translations of app descriptions in the *Play Store*, it seems to me that there isn't any hierarchical resolution logic like there is in Android... there just seems to be a flat list of languages.  So say you only have a translation for Spanish (Spain) available, then in order for that to be used in the US, Latin America and Spain (on the basis that a different variant of Spanish is better than a machine translation of English), do you need to copy that into the US Spanish, Latin American Spanish AND Spanish Spanish slots... there isn't a generic "Spanish" slot?

Answer (score 0):

> But surely if your Spanish translations are actually for es_US, then it doesn't make any sense to treat them as es_419 (because es_US and es_419 are different)?

It can make sense if you only have only one translation to use for both.

> Why not just leave them under es_US, because it seems that for Android 7 they would be found anyway (by traversing up and then down the tree) even if the device was set to es_ES and es_US was the only thing available?

It would be found but it would be slightly slower.

> For a small developer, with just one translation available for a particular language (e.g. only es_ES) is it still a reasonable strategy to stick it into the parent locale folder (e.g. es)?  That way, it should be delivered for any requested variant of Spanish, both pre and post Android 7?

Less than one out of one thousand devices is on pre-7 Android, so it doesn't make sense to support those devices unless you have a legacy codebase, due to the added complexity of backwards compatibility.

If you only have one translation, and say they have their devices set to es_MX, it will search es_MX, then es, then other es children such as es_ES.  If you have only one translation, es is fine.  You might want to put a comment in the XML that it is an es_ES translation but you're putting it in es since you only have one translation (although leaving it in es_ES is fine also, since es_MX devices will use es_ES if they find no es_MX or es directories).

You can test these things out if you have a new and stock enough Android device.  Or emulator.  Set the values directory to one thing, the device to another, and see which particular translation you get.  It will follow what it says on the Android developer web page you linked to.

Comment: "It would be found but it would be slightly slower" -- is the delay really that significant?  I'm imagining maybe a clock cycle or two.

Comment: Just wanted to highlight that **4 out of 5** devices are pre-7 Android, not 1 in a thousand. You might be thinking about API level instead of Android version. (Source: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform)

Answer (score 0):

for the app, use generic folder as long as you don't have a regional variation : aka "es" not "es-US".
So the translation will be used by all ES speakers. (no matter the region)

then you may just overwrite some words like "color vs colour" for en-US vs en-GB.

for the google play store: I'm not sure. as the there is NO "es", but only "es-ES","es-xxx". and the logic seem to be different.